# How to find the minimum number that isn't in a set using stl?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a set of positive integers. How to find the minimum number that isn't contained in the set? Can I do it faster than by O(n)?

For example I have `set s<unsigned int>` where I inserted and erased a lot of numbers. Now I know its size and I want to find the minimum number, such that is not in the set

for set `0 1 2 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 14 15`
the answer is `6`

Comment: Can you do it faster than examining every element in the set?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth for example, if I know that the set contains k elements, and the maximum value is k too, I can

Comment: @Pavel - How would that generalise?  (And how would you know the maximum?)

Comment: Can you post some example values? Are you basically looking for the minimum number - 1? If it is sorted, time is `O(1)`, otherwise `O(n)`

Comment: It's probably not minimum number - 1.  For `{1,2,4}` the answer is `3`.

Comment: @Thilo, I can do it using iterating by O(n). I'm using the set from stl library, it's always sorted, and any new value is inserted in right place

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I updated the question

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, updated

Comment: Can you do it faster than `O(n)`? No.

Comment: Well, then it's `O(N)`. Just start with `0` (you seem to count that as a positive integer), compare with the minimum. If too low, increase and compare with the next element. Worst case you go once through the set.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, and is it any way to change the data submission to do it by O(log n)?

Comment: If you know the first and last entry and size, you can then know if numbers are missing or not quickly (provided numbers are not repeated).  But, as to the missing number, worst case is O(n)

Comment: @Thilo, may be there are any better methods to solve my problem?

Comment: *"any way to change the data submission to do it by O(log n)"* - if you can store the values in a sorted array, then you can use a modified binary search (checking whether there's a gap before an arbitrary index by seeing if `v[i] == i`).  Another alternative is - instead of the binary probe half way through the range of elements still being searched, you might be able to guess that when `v[last] - v[first] / (last - first)` is > 1.0, the gap is statistically likely to be closer to the start of the range, but whether that's valid that depends on how your inputs were generated.

Comment: @TonyD, thank you, I'll try binary search with seeking the last i such that v[i] == i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a set of positive integers. How to find the minimum number that
>   isn't contained in the set?

You'll have to iterate over items in the set, until you find a value that isn't equal to (the previous value plus one).

> Can I do it faster than by O(n)?

Given the task as stated, no -- the first "hole" in your set of numbers could be anywhere in the sequence, which means the number of items you'll need to iterate over until you find that hole will be proportional to the number of items in the set... i.e. the iteration is O(N).

That said, if you are allowed some flexibility in creating your data structures, you might be able to finesse the problem.  For example, instead of building up a single set of numbers, you might start with two sets -- your original set, plus a second set that always contains whatever numbers are not currently included in your first set.  Whenever you insert a number into the first set, you remove it from the second set, and vice-versa.  Then finding the minimum missing number is just a matter of reading the first value in the second set, which is an O(1) operation.  (Of course this is only practical if the range of possible numbers is small, otherwise your second set is going to take up a lot of memory.  If that's a problem, you could reduce memory usage by maintaining a list of [min,max] ranges instead of just individual values, but the code to maintain that will get a bit more complex and might well end up being more expensive than the original/naive O(n) solution)